# How to use specific x-values of a CSV-file for drawing a x-y-plot?

Tags: pgfplots

I have a question concerning `pgfplots`. I have a CSV-file with x-y pairs. The CSV-file is very large (>10k entries).

I want to plot now `x` vs `y`, but only at some specified x-coordinates. In other words, I want to use a reduced data set from my original CSV-file.

For example, suppose x runs over the interval [1,100] in the data file. I want to make a plot with the x-coordinates `x1=0, x2=18, x3=76 and x4=89`. Is there any opportunity to get the corresponding y-values automatically out of the CSV-file or do I need to extract these values externally (Excel, Octave, ...)?

To make it even more complicated: suppose I have an x-value at `x=12.1` and at `x=12.2`. Is there an opportunity to use the nearest point location (in this case x=12.1) if we are  interested in the corresponding y-value at x=12.11?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you want to supply the desired coordinates as a list (like in your example), or do you want sample, say, every 100th coordinate?

Comment: If a pgf-plots "internal solution" does not present itself in various yet to be written answers, you can always read the data file with the `readarray` package, giving you access to individual elements of the file.  Of course, you would have to write your own extraction routines to decide which elements to use. (also, readarray works on space-separated not comma-separated data)

Comment: I think we need more detail here: a demo file showing the pattern (or otherwise) of values to plot and some idea of the type of plot.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\newcommand{\execute}{\x,\y\par}

\begin{document}
\csvreader[head to column names]{test.csv}%
    {}%empty block
    {%x1=0, x2=18, x3=76 and x4=89
        \ifthenelse{\x= 0}{\execute}{\relax}%
        \ifthenelse{\x=18}{\execute}{\relax}%
        \ifthenelse{\x=76}{\execute}{\relax}%
        \ifthenelse{\x=89}{\execute}{\relax}%
    }
\end{document}
```

It assumes a `test.csv` file w/ two columns, the first labeled `x`, the second `y`.

If X isn't always an integer and you want to skip the interstitial values you'll need to round off before making the test.

Comment: I think it'll be very hard to integrate this approach with PGFPlots. Do you have any thoughts on how to plot the selected values?

Comment: Not familiar w/ PGFplots --- could you post a hard-coded minimal working example?